# Non-Hermitian Hamiltonian for electron conductance in electric field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, hamiltonian, conductors, time-evolution

Electron conductance in a solid state is usually driven by electric field - making some direction of jumps more likely.

It makes (e.g. [Hubbard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubbard_model)'s) Hamiltonian no longer self-adjoint, **how to simulate QM with non-Hermitian Hamiltonian? How electron conductance in electric field is being modeled?**

PS. I have just found [non-Hermitian QM Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hermitian_quantum_mechanics), [PI lecture by Carl Bender](https://www.perimeterinstitute.ca/videos/making-sense-non-hermitian-hamiltonians), where he says that PT symmetric Hamiltonian should still have real spectrum. However, I have checked [MERW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_Entropy_Random_Walk)-based [conductance simulator](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ElectronConductanceModelsUsingMaximalEntropyRandomWalks/) which uses Hubbard-like Hamiltonian, and turns out its spectrum has not only real eigenvalues if turning on the potential.

**Update**: Turns out that recently there have started getting popularity approaches related to my 2016 [conductance simulator](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ElectronConductanceModelsUsingMaximalEntropyRandomWalks/), e.g. from https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-24948-2 : "first-order non-Hermitian skin effect arises from the asymmetry between left and right hopping probabilities"

Comment: Can you give some details about why the hamiltonian  is non-self-adjoint?  Is this a boundary condition problem?

Comment: In Hubbard model you have a^+ a terms corresponding to jumps. To have self-adjoint Hamiltonian, both i -> j and j -> i jumps should have the same weights. However, electric field makes one of them more likely.

Comment: More on PT-symmetric QM: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161817/2451

Comment: @Jarek Duda. the diffrent weighting may break left right symmetry, but I should not violate self-adjointness. Are you sure it does? .After all the hamiltonian always has "+ cc" indicating that you add the hermitan to conjugate to eveything.  Can you edit and write down you non-self adjoint Hamiltionian in the question so we can see if there is something missing?

Comment: @mikestone, the "+cc" is exactly adding opposite edges with the same weights. To model conductance we need to add some asymmetry - distinguish the two directions. Maybe it can be introduced in a self-adjoint way? MERW is kind of QM in imaginary time - leads to ground state probability distribution, assumes Boltzmann distribution among paths. The linked conductance simulator adds potential by reducing/increasing energy of right/left step. It means asymmetry in adjacency matrix being minus Hamiltonian, MERW has no problem with that, but I don't know how to realize it in QM, QRW?

Comment: Is the following reference of use? "Waxman's algorithm for non-Hermitian Hamiltonian operators", S R Chamberlain, J G Tucker, J M Conroy and H G Miller Journal of Physics Communications, Volume 2, Number 2. The link to the open access paper is https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2399-6528/aaaea3/meta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than keep up a discussion, I will just write down the hopping part of the Hamiltonian for a 1d Hubbard model in an electric field:
$$
\hat H= \sum_n \left(a^\dagger_{n+1} a_n e^{iA_n(t)} + a^\dagger_{n}a_{n+1} e^{-iA_n(t)}\right)
$$
where 
$$
\frac{\partial A_n}{\partial t}=-E_n(t)
$$
is the electric field.

We can also make a time-dependent change  gauge so that the field is expressed by a scalar potential:
$$
\hat H  =\sum_n \left(a^\dagger_{n+1} a_n  + a^\dagger_{n}a_{n+1} -(\sum_{m=0}^n E_m) a^\dagger_n a_n \right)
$$ 
Both these expressions are self adjoint. In the absence of impurities neither will have a true electric conductivity in a steady field because the eigenstates will undergo Bloch oscillations. I think this  will be true even when interactions are included.  The usual way to get a physically meaningful conductivity is to allow the electric field to depend on space and time, and to take the limit $k\to 0$, and then $\omega \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you, so while in Boltzmann path distribution (MERW) static model is sufficient, here we can add this tendency by time dependent Hamiltonian.